# C# Namespace/class alias in Visual Studio Html Source mode

Tags: c#, namespaces, alias

Is there any way to create a Namespace alias in a .aspx file (not code-behind .aspx.cs).

For example... in a code-behind file an alias can be created as follows:

```
using MyPanel = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel;
```

In html source mode (Visual Studio) a Namespace can be imported as follows:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
```

What I need to do is something like the following:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyPanel = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel" %>
```

**EDIT/UPDATE:** <strike>Obviously that does not work. Is it possible some other way without using code-behind?</strike> Yes, it actually does work if you remove the whitespace (hat tip @Alex below). Example:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyPanel=System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel" %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, your third example does work. You need to get rid of the white space. To get your ASPX namespace alias working, write the namespace declaration like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyPanel=System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel" %>
```

Comment: excelent. I can't believe I never tried removing the spaces. doah.

Answer (score 0):

One contol is blocking another control:theetat
When I am trying to run my codedUITest to set some text in my edit box I get the following error:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException: Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action.
I have had this issue before and I have been able to work around it by clicking on the center of the text box like so:

Mouse.Click(new System.Drawing.Point(sentControl.BoundingRectangle.Width / 2 + sentControl.BoundingRectangle.X,
   sentControl.BoundingRectangle.Height / 2 + sentControl.BoundingRectangle.Y));

Where "sentControl" is the control that you want to click.  Then do a SendKeys("mystuff") to the window as a whole.